# Which countries allow tourists to get married without the long wait for the marriage licence?

Tags: legal, where-on-earth, countries, weddings

I am a 19 year old girl and my guy is 22. We live in the Middle East, and it's hard for us to get married here before I turn 21. We are planning on marrying outside the Middle East.

What countries allow a legal marriage between non-residents, after a short waiting period or with no waiting period?

Comment: Huh? Where are you staying in the Middle East? There is no restriction on age limit for marriages.  You can get married in many places, but the issue is if the marriage is accepted by your country of citizenship.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'd have to verify this, but Las Vegas could be an option.

However, the question is whether your country of residence accepts this marriage; contacting the US consulate of your home country might be a good idea; they would also be able to tell you what you'd have to do to validate your marriage before you leave the US.